# How can you map IDs even when duplicates are eliminated?

Tags: mapping, duplicates, sas, data-conversion

I currently have a large set of objects in SAS (>100000) each with about 60 columns of data, including an ID number. There are many duplicate ID numbers in this set of data. My goal is to convert the ID numbers that I currently have into another form of ID number using a piece of software that I have. The problem is that when I input the ID numbers into the software, the converted output comes back without the duplicates, which I need. Is there any way to use the output ID numbers to somehow create a list of output IDs except with the duplicates that the original set of data had. Any language or piece of software would be fine.

Here is a illustration of what I described above.

Original IDs:  086516   677240   449370   677240   941053   449370

Output: 147244 147947 147957 148021

Preferred Output: 147244 147947 147957 147947 148021 147957

Comment: Show a bit more information here.  You have a dataset with an ID column with duplicate values; you want to append another value based on this ID column.  Is that another value always the same for any given ID value - ie, if I have 15 rows with ID=56 do they all get newID=2345?

Comment: OK, after that edit, another question.  Does your 'other software' give you back the original ID as well as the new ID (as a pair) or only the new ID?  If not, how do you know 147244 goes to 086516?

Comment: Yes, the software gives back a dataset with the original ID and the new ID in two separate columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge on the ID using a MERGE statement, and it will append the value to each of the records with the same ID value.

```
data want;
merge have(in=a) newIDs(in=b);
by id;
if a and b;
run;
```